# Data-flow pipeline in Hadoop HDFS when file copying to DataNodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, dataflow

I just wanted to more about below statement. When I tried to understand [how the HDFS writes happens to Data nodes](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2460260&seqNum=2). I got the below explanation about HDFS writes.

why hdfs client sends 4kb to the Data nodes instead of sending entire block 64MB to the data node? Can some explain in detail?

For better performance, data nodes maintain a pipeline for data transfer. Data node 1 does not need to wait for a complete block to arrive before it can start transferring to data node 2 in the flow. In fact, the data transfer from the client to data node 1 for a given block happens in smaller chunks of 4KB. When data node 1 receives the first 4KB chunk from the client, it stores this chunk in its local repository and immediately starts transferring it to data node 2 in the flow. Likewise, when data node 2 receives first 4KB chunk from data node 1, it stores this chunk in its local repository and immediately starts transferring it to data node 3. This way, all the data nodes in the flow except the last one receive data from the previous one and transfer it to the next data node in the flow, to improve the write performance by avoiding a wait time at each stage.

Comment: can you add the source of the content you posted ?

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2460260&seqNum=2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question have the answer for it.

In this picture lets assume the file size is equal to block size(**128 MB**). So `**A, B, C .. are the chunks in block**`

[image: Data Flow Pipeline]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/REO6r.jpg

> When data node 1 receives the first 4KB(A) chunk from the client, it
> stores this chunk in its local repository and immediately starts
> transferring it to data node 2 in the flow. Likewise, when data node 2
> receives first 4KB chunk from data node 1, it stores this chunk in its
> local repository and immediately starts transferring it to data node 3
>
> **Here the advantage is Data node 2 and 3 need not to wait till 128 MB data is copied to Data node 1 before starts replication. So, the delay because replication will be just one or 2 chucks copy time as all the chunks copied to nodes in parallel**.

Comment: Thanks for making me better understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Hadoop usually files are of large size due to which they are configured for transferring data as soon as they receive some part of it so that they can start processing on it.

Let's discuss it with a example suppose there are 3 data nodes and a map job is to be performed. The data or block in which input file is present is in node 1 and a replication of it is in node 2 (we are assuming replication factor of 2). But due to some reason or may be other job are running on both node 1 and node 2 due to which they are busy thus the map job is now required be perform on node 3 which do not have input file on which we want to perform map job thus that input file is now need to be transferred to this node 3. Now if node manager will wait for whole fie of maybe 64mb to be transferred to node 3 before starting map job then it will definitely have more head over then transfering 4kb. Since 4kb will be transferred more quickly and as soon as node 3 will receive it. it will start map job. Now this is one of the simple scenario of Hadoop.

If you will look into Hadoop streaming data is required to be continuously streaming that is why 4 kB data is transferred between various data node to keep the transfer short and fast and this is also one of major reason why spark streaming is preferred over Hadoop streaming because Hadoop do not transfer continuous data it transfer very small chunk of data that seems like continuous.

You can visit http://javacrunch.in/Yarn.jsp if you want to look into how node manager start any job.

Hope this solve your query.